# Internet Explorer 9 in 2 different computers is showing different views, why is that?

Tags: compatibility

I'm trying to identify the cause of this bizarre situation.

In my computer, in IE9, my website it's viewed in compability mode automaticaly. The browser displays a message "A problem displaying www.swag.com.pt caused Internet Explorer to refresh the page using Compatibility Mode".
This makes the website displaying a lot of errors, missing content, etc. 
And I'm not able to disable this Compability Mode view, it's always showing the same way.

But the most strange thing is that I'm checking in another computer, with the same browser version, and everything looks fine.

What is causing this disparity?

Regards

Comment: Sounds like the Internet Options are different between the two computers, figure out what is different, then report back.

Comment: `www.swag.com.pt` has about [16 errors](http://validator.nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.swag.com.pt%2F) in its HTML5 source. This may have something to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem recently. This might sound daft.. but pretty sure your issue is being caused by the Helvetica font installed on your computer. There's quite a few posts around about it causing a conflict with IE9. Either uninstall the Helvetica font on the computer that's giving you grief or else remove any references to the Helvetica font in your CSS if you have access to the webpage's source.